# REGEXP - how to read " character?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using hadoop pig with regexp (REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL) - this is Java parsing.
I have a string:

```
"DYN_USER_ID=32753477; $Path=\"/\"; DYN_USER_CONFIRM=e6d2a0a7b7715cb10d1dca504e3c5e80; $Path=\"/\"" "Nokia6070/2.0 (03.20) Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1"
```

I'm expeting two groups:

```
First: DYN_USER_ID=32753477; $Path=\"/\"; DYN_USER_CONFIRM=e6d2a0a7b7715cb10d1dca504e3c5e80; $Path=\"/\"

Second: Nokia6070/2.0 (03.20) Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1
```

As you can see, inside the first string there is " character but with escape character \.
The simplies solution is:

```
"(.*)" "(.*)"
```

But is it the best one?

Answer (score 1):

```
"(.*)(?<!\\\\)" "(.*)"
```

This uses **[negatve lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**: `(?<!☀)` where ☀ is some string, here the character backspace is represented by an regex-escaped and String-escaped backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should be using the negated character class `[^"]` so that it matches from the first delimiter `"` to the last delimiter `"`, but the problem is that it ignores escaped `"` characters. If you can have escaped `"` and escaped `\` in your strings, it will be better if you use something like this:

```
"((?:\\.|[^"\\])+)" "((?:\\.|[^"\\])+)"
```

The group `(?:\\.|[^"\\])+` will match either an escaped character or many `[^"\\]` characters.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xD0eX7)